# Erro em Relacionamento noHibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Tenho as seguintes classes

Usuario:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_sega_user")
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "usuario")
public class Usuario {

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Usuario(String usuario, boolean inativo, String nome, String telefoneFixo, String telefoneCelular,
            String cargo, String email, String centroDeCusto, String localidade, String site, String endCompleto,
            String observacao,Set<Perfil> perfis, Set<Secretaria> secretarias) {
        super();
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.inativo = inativo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.telefoneFixo = telefoneFixo;
        this.telefoneCelular = telefoneCelular;
        this.cargo = cargo;
        this.email = email;
        this.centroDeCusto = centroDeCusto;
        this.localidade = localidade;
        this.site = site;
        this.endCompleto = endCompleto;
        this.observacao = observacao;
        this.perfis = perfis;
//        this.secretarias = secretarias;
    }

    @Id
    private String usuario;
    private boolean inativo;
    private String nome;
    private String telefoneFixo;
    private String telefoneFixoOpc;
    private String telefoneCelular;
    private String telefoneCelularOpc;
    private String cargo;
    private String email;
    private String centroDeCusto;
    private String localidade;
    private String site;
    private String endCompleto;
    private String observacao;


    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "portal_sega_perfil", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "perfis_id") })
    private Set<Perfil> perfis = new HashSet<>(); // perfis
    
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private List<String> secretarias;

    
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public boolean isInativo() {
        return inativo;
    }
    

    public void setInativo(boolean ativo) {
        this.inativo = ativo;
    }
    
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Set<Perfil> getPerfis() {
        return perfis;
    }

    public void setPerfis(Set<Perfil> perfis) {
        this.perfis = perfis;
    }

    public String getTelefoneFixo() {
        return telefoneFixo;
    }

    public void setTelefoneFixo(String telefoneFixo) {
        this.telefoneFixo = telefoneFixo;
    }

    public String getTelefoneCelular() {
        return telefoneCelular;
    }

    public void setTelefoneCelular(String telefoneCelular) {
        this.telefoneCelular = telefoneCelular;
    }
    public String getTelefoneFixoOpc() {
        return telefoneFixoOpc;
    }

    public void setTelefoneFixoOpc(String telefoneFixoOpc) {
        this.telefoneFixoOpc = telefoneFixoOpc;
    }

    public String getTelefoneCelularOpc() {
        return telefoneCelularOpc;
    }

    public void setTelefoneCelularOpc(String telefoneCelularOpc) {
        this.telefoneCelularOpc = telefoneCelularOpc;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCentroDeCusto() {
        return centroDeCusto;
    }

    public void setCentroDeCusto(String centroDeCusto) {
        this.centroDeCusto = centroDeCusto;
    }

    public String getLocalidade() {
        return localidade;
    }

    public void setLocalidade(String localidade) {
        this.localidade = localidade;
    }

    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    public String getEndCompleto() {
        return endCompleto;
    }

    public void setEndCompleto(String endCompleto) {
        this.endCompleto = endCompleto;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }
}
```

E

Secretaria

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_sega_vip_secretaria")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
public class Secretaria implements Serializable {
/*
 * chave composta da tabela tb_sega_vip_secretaria
 */
@Id
private String id_vip;
@Id
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "secretarias",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<String> id_secretaria;

/*
 * tipo de secretaria 1 = primaria 2 = secundaria
 */
private Integer tipo;


public Integer getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(Integer tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getId_vip() {
    return id_vip;
}

public void setId_vip(String id_vip) {
    this.id_vip = id_vip;
}

public List<String> getId_secretaria() {
    return id_secretaria;
}

public void setId_secretaria(List<String> id_secretaria) {
    this.id_secretaria = id_secretaria;
}
```

}

E apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on br.com.claro.tcc.web.portalsega.model.Usuario.secretarias references an unknown entity: java.util.List
```

Alguma sugestão de solução?
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Em qual tabela fica a coluna secretaria_id? Fica na tabela usuario?

Na classe Usuario voce tem:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
private List<String> secretarias;
```

Deveria ser algo como:

```
@JoinColumn(name="SECRETARIA_ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Secretaria secretaria;
```

Na classe Secretaria voce tem:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "secretarias")
private List<String> id_secretaria;
```

Deveria ser algo como:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "secretaria")
private List<Usuario> usuarios;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: a secretaria_id fica dentro de tb_sega_vip_secretaria, eu fiz a alteração para receber o objeto Secretaria, desenhei exatamente assim como vc propôs, entretanto o erro permanece, acredito que o problema seja no relacionamento das tabelas, algo que estou deixando passar.